# Filter table by another table based on date field

Tags: dax, powerquery

I have a detail table in my model with a row for every hour in a day and the sales amount generated to that point of the date. Its not displayed on my report, rather it acts as the base for another reference table in the model:

Datetime             Sales
2019-11-10 06:00:00   100.00
2019-11-10 12:00:00   200.00
2019-11-10 18:00:00   500.00
2019-11-10 23:59:59   999.00

The first (reference) table in the model only displays in my report the last hour value of each day in my base table. they are related via the datetime field using a 1:M with a single cross filter setting:

let
    Source = Base,
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Datetime] = #time(23, 59, 59)))
in
    #"Filtered Rows"

Datetime             Sales
2019-11-10 23:59:59   999.00
2019-11-11 23:59:59   950.00
2019-11-12 23:59:59   900.00

I would like to place a third table on my report that shows each of the hourly rows from the base table when a user clicks on a row in the daily table with the default setting being today's data which is added hourly.

I went down the path of using Power Query to try and filter the base table but have not been able to make it work. Should this instead be done using DAX? Either way, what would the query look like?
thanks in advance!

Comment: it'd help if you post a screenshot of your data model

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but I have just resolved this. By changing my relationship to use a date field instead of the datetime field, and changing it to a (*:1) type, i am now getting the filter to do what I want. Now just have to figure out how to default to today's date. Thanks again!